# show post request response with springframework

Tags: android, spring, codeigniter

I have a problem right now, what happens is that I have an api rest with codeigniter, I make the post request and it returns a json that I need to use to show in my app. I use `RestTemplate` but I can not get the answer to show it. Thanks for your help.

the response with postman is:

```
{"response": "iiprak"}
```

and my app code:

```
public String generate(Coupon coupon){
    try {
        Map<String, Integer> values = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        values.put("id_client", coupon.getId_client());
        values.put("id_promo", coupon.getId_promo());
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(values);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(jsonObject.toString(), headers);
        //restTemplate.postForEntity(BASE_URL, entity, null);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(BASE_URL, entity, null);

        String coupon = response.getBody();
        return coupon;
    } catch (Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are calling `restTemplate.postForEntity()` from the UI thread. You cannot make networking calls from the UI thread. In your case it will [throw an exception](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#intro) and the `return null` happens.

Try to make the call in an `AsyncTask` or a `Thread` with `Handler`s.

There's a good example using the Spring framework and `AsyncTask` here - https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-android/.

Example from the above page with your requirements:

```
private class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            // BELOW IS YOUR CODE IN QUESTION, I am not validating it.
            Map<String, Integer> values = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            values.put("id_client", coupon.getId_client());
            values.put("id_promo", coupon.getId_promo());
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(values);
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(jsonObject.toString(), headers);
            //restTemplate.postForEntity(BASE_URL, entity, null);
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(BASE_URL, entity, null);

            String coupon = response.getBody();
            return coupon;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String coupon) {
        couponTextView.setText("Coupon is: " + coupon);
    }

}
```

Now you can execute the task like this:

```
new HttpRequestTask().execute();
```

Comment: agradezco tu ayuda, he probado tu ejemplo pero no consigo mostrar el resultado aún, ademas como envio los parametros con el values.put. Menciono tambien que estoy dentro de un fragmento.